# how to plot after data load from csv in d3

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am working with the hex binning example given at: http://bl.ocks.org/4248145

I want to make a modification to read the data from a csv that contains columns x and y for the points.

Want to modify this line:

```
var points = d3.range(2000).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });
```

so that points contains the two columns of data.

How can I generate the points variable from two columns of data from a csv?  Since the hex binning takes an entire array (all rows at once) , d3.csv doesn't seem to cut it since it is asynchronous and the function for a callback is on each row of the data -- is there a way to set the points variable to the data in the csv file, and then plot only once that call is complete?

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of the question, but you are mistaken about .csv calling back for each row. You should get a single callback with the content of the csv parsed into an array of objects whose keys are based on the header values in the first row